# I need to do a condition in Power Shell

Tags: powershell

I'm searching a version of some files by Power Shell, example:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem "C:\*\packetbeat.exe" -Recurse |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty VersionInfo |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProductVersion
```

And it shows me:

> 7.8.0

But I need to wait for the command finish its function, in this case the command will find in all disk C

I need finish this task when the first match appears.

Comment: hi, perhaps `Select-Object VersionInfo, ProductVersion` to get both attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the search to stop after the first match, you can use this:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem "C:\*\packetbeat.exe" -Recurse |
    Select-Object -First 1 |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty VersionInfo |
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProductVersion
```